# Why does firstChild not return the first element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was writing some code the other day, and for some reason, I had no idea why this happened, but this was part of the code that I had written.

```
    var item = document.getElementByClass('object');
    var innerImageId = item.firstChild.id;
```

I went over this code a lot of times. The problem of this code is that the value of innerImageId is undefined. The firstChild of item is an image. I need to get the id of the image, but no matter how many times I went over the code, it did not work. Here is the HTML file of the code.

```
    <div class="object inventory-box">
        <img src="image.png" id="sample-image">
    </div>
```

Doesn't this seem correct? Well, I did some debugging in Google Chrome, and it turns out that there are 3 nodes in the div "object". The id of the first and the last node was undefined, but the 2nd one was "sample-image". 
I then tried "firstElementChild" instead of "firstChild", and this worked well.

Then just to test it out, I did something like this-

```
    <div class="object inventory-box">



       <img src="image.png" id="sample-image">



    </div>
```

(or with multiple lines of unnecessary whitespace)

but it still shows 3 nodes, the enter symbol, the div, and another enter symbol.
This problem keeps occurring in Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Can someone please explain why there are these random 2 extra nodes?

Comment: there are empty text nodes before and after the image. you can fix html by removing whitespace between tags. --> `<div><img /></div>`

Comment: @WhiteHat I did try that, but I forgot to mention it in the question. The `div` really should still have one node, because it is just ridiculous to have that in a browser.

Comment: @RonitJoshi Well, then let's just redefine the way the DOM has worked for decades so it doesn't seem ridiculous to you. White space is white space and must be represented. It's represented as a node. If you're interested in **elements** instead of **nodes**, you already found there is an entire set of APIs for that (such as `firstElementChild`)--use them. MDN docs on `firstChild` explain the problem quite clearly. Also, please edit your questions more carefully. `var item = document.getElementByClass('object');` would have immediately stopped the interpreter since their is no such API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about behavior which is clearly described in the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

The browser insert a text node when there are white spaces or new lines in your code. You are targeting one of those.

Try

```
var img = document.querySelector('.object img');
var innerImageId = img.id;
```

Comment: You're right that he's getting a text node.  OP could also just replace `firstChild` with `firstElementChild` to get the correct behavior.

Comment: Isn't firstElementChild unsupported on IE and Safari?

Comment: @LCatallo, it's supported in current versions of both.  Looks like `querySelector` is supported slightly further back in both browsers, versions [8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Browser_Compatibility) vs. [9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode#Browser_compatibility) for IE and 3.2 vs. 4.0 for Safari.

Comment: @NoahFreitas you are right, i misread the support table on MDN.

Comment: Not "most browsers". HTML parsing is well defined. And it's not "by default". It's because he added whitespace between them.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `firstElementChild` in place of `firstChild` which will skip those empty text nodes.

EDIT: Blah thanks BAM5 just not paying attention as I typed.

Answer (score 3):

1. There isn't a `getElementByClass` method, this is why you failed. Open console and you'll see JS error. I guess what you thought were `getElementsByClassName`. Note it's in plural form, and it returns an array-like.
2. Even if you get over the first issue, you may still fail due to your markup. `firstChild` does return the **first** one among children, including the text nodes. Your better choice is `firstElementChild`. Or you have to write like this to avoid text node children:

   ```
   <div><img></div>
   ```

---

So, this should give what you wanted:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('object');
var innerImageId = items[0].firstElementChild.id;
```

On the other hand, other answers pointed that `querySelector` can do the job, indeed. And it has a brother `querySelectorAll`. You could search MDN for their usages and slight difference in between.

Answer (score 2):

Use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`. As l. Catallo said, you may be getting a text node instead of an element.

Looks like Atheist beat me to it, but in his answer he incorrectly used `firstChildElement`. Would comment, but not enough rep...

Comment: Thanks. Just wasn't paying attention as I typed. =]

Comment: Oh sweet, I can comment on my own answers! No prob, I do it all the time :P

Comment: @BAM5 - I know about the firstElementChild method, but I just thought it was extremely ridiculous that browsers would actually count something like that as a text node.

Comment: I mean, you should be able to program with any style you want, am I right?

Comment: @RonitJoshi If you are right, how should someone who want to get a text node do?

Comment: @RonitJoshi Absolutely you can program with any style you like. Personally I use K&R. But that's just code formatting. Discrepancies like this between browsers are why properties like `firstElementChild` exist, and to not use it  and have your code break just because you like `firstChild` is silly :P Also, I believe that any characters in html will create a text node. If you were to put the elements right next to each other in text (eg <div><div>) there would be no text node. Adding a line break and white space count as a text node.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar question while I was learning DOM exploration and I observed that, when there is a space or the next tag is on the next line, the node list normally shows a text node. For Example:
If I wrote my HTML code as below, and tried to get all the child nodes of the element body.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <h2> Lets Study DOM!! </h2>
    <input type = 'text' id = 'topic'> </input></br>
    <button onClick = addToList()> Click Me to Add </button>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('body').childNodes);
```

The above code gave me the following output:

```
[text, h2, text, input#topic, text, br, text, button, text, ul#unordered, text, script]
```

On the other hand, if I modified my code as shown below, and then tried to print the node list, I got a different output as shown below:

HTML Code:

```
<body><h2> Lets Study DOM!! </h2>
        <input type = 'text' id = 'topic'> </input></br>
        <button onClick = addToList()> Click Me to Add </button>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('body').childNodes);
```

The above code gave me the following output:

```
[h2, text, input#topic, text, br, text, button, text, ul#unordered, text, script]
```

So clearly, the browser considers the space after the body tag as a text node.