# Why is my nodeValue property not working?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'd expect the console to display Monday. I've tried to use the innerText and outerText properties but without success either.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("ul");
var child = el.firstChild.nodeValue;
console.log(child)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul class="green">
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
  </ul>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working. It's just that the `firstChild` of the `<ul>` is the whitespace between the `<ul>` and `<li>`, so it's "invisible".

Comment: As is written above, `firstChild` is Text node. Use `firstElementChild` instead. Or `getElementsByTagName/querySelector`.

Comment: `el.querySelector("li")` is better than `el.getElementsByTagName("li")[0]`

Comment: Is there a better dupe than [Why does firstChild not return the first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095991/why-does-firstchild-not-return-the-first-element)?

Answer (score 1):

`el.firstChild` is the newline character after the opening `<ul>` (check its [`.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) which will be `3` for `#TextNode`)

```js
const el = document.querySelector("ul");
console.log(el.firstChild.nodeType)
```

```html
<ul class="green">
  <li>Monday</li>
  <li>Tuesday</li>
</ul>
```

Use [`.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) instead to get the first `Element` which is the first `<li>` in this case

```js
const el = document.querySelector("ul");
const li = el.firstElementChild;
console.log(li.textContent)
```

```html
<ul class="green">
  <li>Monday</li>
  <li>Tuesday</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: or `el.querySelector("li")`

Comment: @mplungjan Or this. But for the sake of explanation I used `.firstElementChild`